# How to set the Screen Saver Grace Period for Windows 8?

Tags: windows-registry, windows-8-preview, screensaver

I manually added the `ScreenSaverGracePeriod` (REG_DWORD) value in seconds to the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` registry key and it didn't enable the screen saver grace period in Windows 8 (64-bit consumer preview). Has this functionality been removed, or is there a different way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have added ScreenSaverGracePeriod as a REG_SZ (string value) as I remember reading something about a controversy of REG_DWORD v REG_SZ in Windows 7.

It worked for me in Windows 8 consumer.  I used ScreenSaverGracePeriod values such as 5 and 60, and I did not even have to sign out for it to give me the grace period. The time before the screen actually locked when once the screen saver activated.

Comment: Worked once I changed it to a REG_SZ and removed the trailing space from the value name. Thanks!

Comment: An integer stored as a string? Well that makes sense! Also interesting, according to [MS KB221784](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/221784), it value had to be REG_SZ in NT4 and 2000, but REG_DWORD in XP and 2003. And now it seems, we're back to REG_SZ. WHY?

Answer (score 1):

I gave registry settings a try, but no luck, I think because of domain caveats. Here's a workaround that works for me.

1. Go to Power Options
2. Click “Change plan settings” for your current plan
3. Click “Change advanced power settings”
4. Expand the Display item
5. Change “Dim display after” to a number that you’re happy with
6. Change “Turn off display after” to one minute more than the dim value that you just set
7. Change “Dimmed display brightness” to 10% (or a value that you’re happy with)

I changed mine only for “Plugged in” but I may change it in “On battery” as well.