Windows 11 - Display won't turn off
Been trying to resolve this issue for a while now...
I have my setting set to display off after 5 minutes. (For testing purposes I changed it to 1 minute).
If I restart my computer - and just turn on all my programs I have on idle (steam, chrome w/ tabs, etc.) it will work completely fine and display will turn off
However... after I use my computer for a bit (ie. youtube, browsing etc.) with no additional programs opened since above - the display will no longer turn off
I tried looking into powercfg /requests - shows nothing
Dived into powercfg /sleepstudy - it shows all occurrences as mouse input or keyboard input
Right after that - i unplugged all usb devices from my computer, it still will not turn off the monitor
So I started to end task in task manager on programs - issue still persists
USB Selective suspend settings is: Disabled (was originally enabled)
Not sure if this makes any difference - PCI Express Link State Power Management is: OFF
I've updated all my drivers (GPU, windows update etc.)
I've uninstalled logitech hub? - and even chcked if my mx master 3s firmware is up to date
Nothing seems to work.
I cannot figure out what is causing this issue.
Appreciate everyones input.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Note that there is Grace Period for the screen saver (lock screen), https://superuser.com/questions/418118/how-to-set-the-screen-saver-grace-period-for-windows-8 (and in newer versions) that may add to the timeout. Also, if mouse/keyboard keep it awake, try unplugging 'em, or using different ones.
